# Element [control_name] is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the web.config file is missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I know that this probably seems like a repeated question but trust me, I have done my research and found nothing that works for me. So you guys are my only hope before I have to re-install VS 2013

Right, before I go any further, I am using Visual Studio 2013 with .net framework and I have a very moderate idea about VS.

This is my aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Images.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestPage.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet2.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Maze.png" runat="server" CssClass="ImgHolder" />
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" EmptyDataText="No Files found!" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="ImgGrid" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="ImgNum, ImgContent">
            <HeaderStyle Height="30px" BackColor="#FF9E66" Font-Size="15px" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
            <RowStyle Height="20px" Font-Size="13px" HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ImgNum" HeaderText="#" />
                <asp:Image runat="server"></asp:Image>         <%--Here lies the problem--%>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I have used the Image control in 2 places. While it works perfectly outside the GridView, it (and practically any asp control) shows me:

> Element [control_name] is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the web.config file is missing.

I have already tried:

- Closing my VS and going to `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ReflectedSchemas` to delete all cached files in there, and then open it. Zero success.
- I have even used the same code in another new project. Zero success.
- One article asked to check the webconfig files of the .net framework in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework` but I couldn't find 4.5 in it, so I checked 4.0 and everything seemed perfect as per the article. Although, I can't imagine how not having 4.5 in the directory is a problem since all other controls are working fine

So, as you can see that I have put in quite a bit of work into this and have had no success.

So, please tell me what I am missing? Or would I have to reinstall Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the tag "column" you only can set Columns, you can't add everý asp element that you want. If your grid has a column which only has images, you have to use

```
<asp:ImageField>
```

instead of

```
<asp:image>
```

Answer (score 0):

When Your Build Website is success and getting Element [control_name] is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the web.config file is missing.

You Can Change Target Schema For Validation To **HTML5**. After That it will not Showing Error in Controller.